Logging in azure with dotnet 8
How should I handle logging in a Azure environment with a event driven microservice architecture?
The microservices are Azure functions, which then adds/reads data from a Azure CosmosDb. I Also have events which should do aggregation of data etc in cosmos when the request returns 200.
From the top of my head, this is the solution I come up with:
1. Create a Common Logger nuget package that uses OpenTelemetry, which is used by all microservices.
2. Request headers should always include traceId, or a random one should be generated upon the first request.
3. All events should have a message property that includes both message and traceId.
Now, is there something I'm missing? Is there a simpler way by using the correct header names that this could automate by using openTelemetry or Application Insights?

What is your logging supposed to accomplish? Logging-for-auditing is not the same thing as logging-for-fault-observability, for example.

...and are you aware of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging and the rest?

Good question. I guess I want to achieve a logging-for-fault. Logging in HTTP with http status code is kind of easy. But as soon as I have events, I find it harder. Let's say the following flow:
POST (bff) -> Azure Function -> Cosmos DB, this is the easy flow since I always have control over traceId. Now if I instead do this:
POST (bff) -> Azure Function 1 -> Cosmos DB -> EVENT to Azure Function 2 -> Event to Cosmos DB
How can I preserve the traceId in case 2 for example.

What you're describing already exists in ASP.NET Core - and preserving/following the traceId is done via CorrelationIds.
